# Accessing environment variables of downstream matrix job

Tags: jenkins, cicd

I want to pass a variable from downstream job to upstream one.

A - Upstream job
B - Downstream job (Matrix: B1, B2 ,B3)

B1/B2/B3 during build have identical property which needs to be passed to A.

The only way I figured out is to do that via environment variables. Basically:
B sets environment variable "foo=bar"
And in A job:

```
def result = build job "B" 
def myDesiredValue = result.getBuildVariables().foo
```

But the issue is that B job is user-defined matrix job and when I set environment variable in B1,B2,B3 matrixes - it's not returned with the job result.

Is there any way to either:

1. Inject env. variable from matrix B1/B2/B3 to B so it would appear under env. variables
2. Access env. variable of B1/B2/B3 in A job directly?